# How to create an empty iterator for a certain collection type (list/set/map) in Rust?

Tags: iterator, rust

I want to write a method which returns an iterator for a collection (e.g.
`LinkedList`). But in some cases there's no suitable collection to return an
iterator for. In such cases I'd like to return an "empty" iterator which
iterates over no elements. But I couldn't find any associated function to
construct a `linked_list::Iter` in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/linked_list/struct.Iter.html).

Consider the following example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::LinkedList;
use std::collections::linked_list;

pub struct Graph {
    nodes: HashMap<usize, LinkedList<usize>>,
}

impl Graph {
    pub fn adjacent_nodes(&self, node: usize) -> linked_list::Iter<usize> {
        match self.nodes.get(&node) {
            Some(x) => x.iter(),
            _ => linked_list::Iter::<usize>::new()
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to return an iterator over adjacent nodes from the `adjacent_nodes`
method. But when asked for neighbours of a non-existing node, the method should
return an iterator over nothing, obviously. But how could I create it? The code
I gave doesn't compile actually:

```
src/graph.rs:13:18: 13:49 error: no associated item named `new` found for type
        `collections::linked_list::Iter<'_, usize>` in the current scope
src/graph.rs:13             _ => linked_list::Iter::<usize>::new()
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess, I could solve the problem with `boxed::Box` but it is clearly a
suboptimal solution because of unnecessary heap allocation that I try to avoid.

So, my question is: Is it possible in Rust to create an iterator-over-nothing of
specific type?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot do it, not with by-reference iterators, because they are always tied to a concrete collection instance.

What you can do is to return boxed iterator as a trait object:

```
pub fn adjacent_nodes<'a>(&'a self, node: usize) -> Box<Iterator<Item=usize>+'a> {
    match self.nodes.get(&node) {
        Some(x) => Box::new(x.iter()),
        _ => Box::new(::std::iter::empty())
    }
}
```

[`std::iter::empty()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.empty.html) returns an empty iterator, but of course its type is different from those of collection iterators, so you have to use a trait object. I also had to add a lifetime parameter because the iterator returned by `iter()` is tied to `self.nodes`, and you need to explain it to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't quite understand why an empty iterator has to be tied to a concrete collection instance. It looks to me like a flaw in the standard library. An unnecessary heap allocation like this is certainly not a zero cost abstraction.

Comment: It's if you need that particular type. The slice iterator is an exception: `[].iter()` and `[].iter_mut()` both should be fine.

Comment: I'd use an enum of the two cases rather than using a boxed iterator.

Comment: @bluss, isn't `[]` an empty array? It has the same ownership semantics and will be destroyed after the function ends, so you can't return an iterator from it. Also, enum with two cases would require manual implementation of `Iterator`, but yes, it is a viable solution.

Comment: @Nikolai, there is no difference between empty and non-empty iterators. What matters is iterator type. `Iterator` is a trait, and there are types which implement this trait. Each collection has its own iterator type because data structures are different, and iterators must know about collection implementation. Therefore, iterators for different collections are incompatible. More problems arise when iterators are yielding references, because then they are tied to collections via lifetime parameters in types.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev [It's fine,](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8f76cbfa64d418f8b364&version=stable) rust gives out a static empty array.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. This won't work for anything except slices, though.

Comment: Does the compiler optimize it away somehow? This is unnecessarily allocating heap memory somehow.