# Conditionally return empty iterator from flat_map

Tags: iterator, rust, iteration

Given this definition for `foo`:

```
let foo = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6], vec![7, 8, 9]];
```

I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
let result: Vec<_> = foo.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(i, row)| if i % 2 == 0 {
        row.iter().map(|x| x * 2)
    } else {
        std::iter::empty()
    })
    .collect();
```

but that raises an error about the if and else clauses having incompatible types. I tried removing the `map` temporarily and I tried defining an empty vector outside the closure and returning an iterator over that like so:

```
let empty = vec![];

let result: Vec<_> = foo.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(i, row)| if i % 2 == 0 {
        row.iter() //.map(|x| x * 2)
    } else {
        empty.iter()
    })
    .collect();
```

This seems kind of silly but it compiles. If I try to uncomment the `map` then it still complains about the if and else clauses having incompatible types. Here's part of the error message:

```
error[E0308]: if and else have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:6:30
   |
6  |           .flat_map(|(i, row)| if i % 2 == 0 {
   |  ______________________________^
7  | |             row.iter().map(|x| x * 2)
8  | |         } else {
9  | |             std::iter::empty()
10 | |         })
   | |_________^ expected struct `std::iter::Map`, found struct `std::iter::Empty`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:7:28: 7:37]>`
              found type `std::iter::Empty<_>`
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d33ff7da39455fa55ecef524b91ea0e9&version=stable)

I know I could write something that does what I want with some nested `for` loops but I'd like to know if there's a terse way to write it using iterators.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284362/how-to-create-an-empty-iterator-for-a-certain-collection-type-list-set-map-in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Rust is statically typed and each step in an iterator chain changes the result to a new type that entrains the previous types (unless you use boxed trait objects) you will have to write it in a way where both branches are covered by the same types.

One way to convey conditional emptiness with a single type is the [`TakeWhile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.TakeWhile.html) iterator implementation.

```
.flat_map(|(i, row)| {
    let iter = row.iter().map(|x| x * 2);
    let take = i % 2 == 0;
    iter.take_while(|_| take)
})
```

If you don't mind ignoring the edge-case where the input iterator `foo` could have more than `usize` elements you could also use `Take` instead with either 0 or usize::MAX. It has the advantage of providing a better `size_hint()` than `TakeWhile`.

Comment: "*`|_| if i % 2 == 0 {true} else {false}`*" Please, just `|_| i % 2 == 0`... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn hah, yes. I also hoisted the modulo out of the closure. although the compiler might be able to optimize it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In your specific example, you can use [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) to remove unwanted elements prior to calling `flat_map`:

```
let result: Vec<_> = foo.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter(|&(i, _)| i % 2 == 0)
    .flat_map(|(_, row)| row.iter().map(|x| x * 2))
    .collect();
```

If you ever want to use it with `map` instead of `flat_map`, you can combine the calls to `filter` and `map` by using [filter_map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) which takes a function returning an `Option` and only keeps elements that are `Some(thing)`.